# How can I display vertical text in XSL

Tags: xslt

I have some XSL used as a representation to describe the layout of a PDF/Letter. One of the requirements is to have some text displayed vertically down the right hand side of it. I have searched this subject but have not really found a definitive or clear answer.

I have tried to attach an image would help show what I am trying to achieve but because I am new on here it will not let me. This is what I have got so far, but as yet I have not got it to work (or even display the text!)

```
                <fo:block-container writing-mode="tb-lr">
                    <fo:block intrusion-displace="line">        
                      <fo:float float="start">
                          <fo:block text-align="center" border="1pt solid gray" font="bold italic 9pt Helvetica">               
                              <fo:block>
                                Floaty Vertical Text
                              </fo:block>
                        </fo:block>
                      </fo:float>            
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:block-container>
```

Are any of you wise people able to tell how I would accomplish this? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue by further reading, the main thing I needed to do was to understand XSL-FO basics which in turn allowed me to understand what was required more clearly. This is a snippet showing how I achieved my issue:

```
        <fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4"  page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="1.27cm" margin-bottom="1.27cm" margin-left="1.75cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="1mm" margin-bottom="1mm" /> 
                <fo:region-before region-name="header-normal" extent="0mm" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="footer-normal" extent="0mm" />
                <fo:region-end region-name="right-sidebar" writing-mode="tb-rl" extent="10mm" />                    
            </fo:simple-page-master>

        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4" font-family="sans-serif">

        <!-- Output the BARR string -->
            <fo:static-content flow-name="right-sidebar" font-size="4pt">                           
                <fo:block padding-before="4pt"text-align="left">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$BARRstring" />
                </fo:block>                 
            </fo:static-content>
```

Very straight forward once you know how! Just needed to create a new region-end and set the writing-mode to tb-rl, then reference the region within the page-sequence.

Hope this helps anybody else trying to do the same thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `reference-orientation="90"`

```
<fo:block-container reference-orientation="90" display-align="center" inline-progression-dimension="6cm">
                                                    <fo:block>barra</fo:block>
                                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">91219934073AA1123</fo:block>
                                                </fo:block-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is viable, but as an alternate approach, you can set the `reference-orientation` of the corresponding `fo:static-content` element to the appropriate value. If you want the text to flow from top to bottom, for example, you could set the attribute's value to `270`:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="right-sidebar" font-size="4pt" reference-orientation="270">
<!-- Put content here -->
</fo:static-content>
```